# Get name of current fragment in activity. Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-framelayout

I have an framelayout which loads 6 different fragment. Is there any way to find the name of the current fragment in framelayout from activity.

Fragment1

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.main,Fragment.instantiate(LoadingScreen.this,
                    "com.myapp.fragments.fragment1",bundle)).commit();
```

Fragment2

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.main,Fragment.instantiate(LoadingScreen.this,
                    "com.myapp.fragments.fragment2",bundle)).commit();
```

I need to know which fragment is live in the framelayout, from activity. Since two different fragments are loaded in the same layout.

Comment: Post your relevant source code as well. This information is not enough

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which fragment is loaded in the layout, you can do something like this:

```
    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main);
    if(f instanceof Fragment1){
      //do something
    }
    else if(f instanceof Fragment2){
     //do something
    }
```

If you want to know class name then use:

```
String name = f.getClass().getCanonicalName()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findFragmentById()` it will return the current fragment in the container.